# Variable Inspector in debug mode does not display Values of Guid and DateTime - Visual Studio 2019 (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I debug my application I can use mouse over to view the values of the object. But when I am in my Xamarin Forms application the value is not shown for fields like Guid and DateTime. Instead there is {System.Guid} or {System.DateTime}.

[image: variavle inspector displaying System.Guid instead of the value]

This is not the case if i hover over the field directly, but for the most cases i have to see the value inside the object.

[image: mouse over field directly exposes guid value]

If I manually enter the corresponding variable in the Monitor tab, it also says {System.Guid}, but if I double-click on it, the value is displayed.

[image: monitor tab exposes value of guid (double-click)]

This makes debugging the application very tedious. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I think it's by design.